# Bitwise OR of two binary numbers

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

Taken from a Computer Systems and Networks Past Paper:

**This question is about assembly language
a) Explain what the bitwise or of two binary numbers is. Given an example. [5 marks]**

I'm just doing some general revision and since there are no mark schemes its kind of hard to tell if i am right, so i would like some advice or to be pointed in the right direction.

**What I think:**
The bitwise OR in our case takes two binary numbers of equal length and performs logical inclusive OR on them.

```
Example:  0101
       OR 0111
       --------
          0111
```

Do you think this answer would be sufficient enough?

Comment: I believe it is, although that "equal length" restriction is not enforced. The shorter operand type should be implicitly converted to the wider operand's type before the operation.

Comment: I like to think of OR operation as *bits joiner*, e.g. `11000000 OR 00000011 = 11000011`.

Comment: Equal length is mandatory, I wouldn't even mention it, it only adds confusion potential. Operand conversion and the "or" operation itself are two completely different things, each has its own definition.

Comment: I think the phrase, *performs logical inclusive OR on them* is a too vague. It should read, *performs logical inclusive OR on corresponding bits in the same relative bit positions of the operands to determine the bits in the result*.

Comment: Thanks lurker, you're right it was probably too vague! Your answer was a lot better! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise `OR`  of any two bits is `1` if either of the two source bits is `1`

If this is your definition of *inclusive OR* then yes, you are correct.

Your question may want a "truth table", something like this

```
 OR    0  1
    ._________
  0 |  0  1
    |
  1 |  1  1
```

Sorry for my lousy ascii formatting, best I can do at the moment.

At any rate, the result in the destination is `1` if either bit was `1` in either of the sources.